# R - How to make a plot with two variables on the horizontal axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I'm a rookie in R.

This is my date frame:

```
 I  UserID | hour | min | velocity
   #1    1        0     0      12
   #2    1        0     30     20
   #3    1        1     0      19
   #4    1        1     30     11
   #5    1        2     0      12
   #6    1        2     30     7
   ..   ...     ...    ...   ....
   #10   2        0     0      142
   #11   2        0     30     201
   #12   2        1     0      129
   #13   2        1     30     111
   ..   ...     ...    ...   ....
```

I put the Userid column as a factor.

My question is how can I make a linear graph using as the horizontal axis the hour and minute column and velocity as the vertical axis?

Comment: My best recommendation would be to make a single "Time" column, you can make numeric, time or POSIXct with only time. see inspiration [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html), also you might want to check [this](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf) ggplot2 cheatsheet to understand how to plot. remember that SO is here to help you solve problems not write everything for you.

Comment: I would combine the `hour` and `min` variable into one time variable (e.g. secs since a particular time) and simply plot one axis.

Comment: Please show some effort to solve the probme yourself, we are not your personal coding service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only time to appear in x-axis, you can create a dummy date "2018-01-01" in this case and exclude it from the plot

```
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
df$Time=ymd_hm(paste0("2018-01-01"," ",as.character(df$hour),":",as.character(df$min)))
ggplot(df,aes(x=Time,y=velocity))+geom_line()+scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to combine time - maybe to show what happens at half hour intervals - or for any other reason, here's what can be useful:

**DATA**

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(userID = c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10)),
                  hour = 1:20,
                  min = c(0,30),
                  velocity = runif(20, 12,111))
```

**PLOT**

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = hour, y = velocity)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(min), color = factor(userID)))
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: Time not combined]

If you want to add lines, change the `geom_point()` to `geom_line()` and use the `linetype` attribute instead of `shape` with its value set to `factor(min)`.

If you do not mind combining `hour` and `min` into the x-axis, you can use the below code:

```
# add another column
dat$tme <- as.POSIXct(paste("2018-02-01", dat$hour, dat$min), 
                      format = "%Y-%m-%d %H %M", tz = "UTC")
```

**PLOT**

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = tme, y = velocity)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(userID)))
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: Time combined into 1 variable]